# How to automount removable devices with options?

Tags: filesystem, xfce, automount

I'd like to **automount** (using the XFCE desktop) USB devices with **Btrfs**. This works as with any other filesystem just by plugging it in and waiting for two or three seconds for it to appear under `/media/...`

Unfortunately, it is mounted with the default mount options only. I would like to mount it with additional options, e.g. compress.

*How would I do that?*

I've tried to add an entry with UUID=... to `/etc/fstab`. It then mounts with the wanted option, but not automatically anymore. I need to manually call `udisks --mount /dev/sdb1` then.

Formerly, gnome had entries like `/system/storage/default_options/ext3/mount_options`
where the default mount options could be configured, but I did not see that under XFCE, and it applies to all filesystems of that type.

So this boils down to the question:

*How can I have specific options configured in `/etc/fstab` and still have XFCE automount the device?*

Comment: Probably creating a `udev` rule is the best way to specify exactly what you want, as there's no `mount.rc` in recent Xfce versions.

Answer (score 0):

The Thunar Volume Manager is an extension for the Thunar file manager, which enables automatic management of removable drives and media. If `thunar-volman` is installed and configured properly, for example, and you plug in your removable media, it will automatically launch your preferred application and auto-mount your media. 
More details can be found [here](http://goodies.xfce.org/projects/thunar-plugins/thunar-volman) and [here](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/using-removable-media) at the official XFCE site.